# yylloc undefined in this scope

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have the following problem while compiling the files. I have overwritten the definition of YYLTYPE as follows(though it is the same as default but I will extend it

```
typedef struct YYLTYPE  
{  
  int first_line;  
  int first_column;  
  int last_line;  
  int last_column;  
} YYLTYPE;
```

and when I add the following in the lex file I get the "yylloc undefined in this scope" error.

```
#define YY_USER_INIT yylloc.first_line = yylloc.first_column = 1;
```

## Pastebin:

- [flex file](http://www.pastebin.com/wpX7YVpa)
- [bison file](http://www.pastebin.com/4t0FmCMD)
- [makefile](http://www.pastebin.com/nTqGnuZV)

Comment: I assume you meant to tag this as gnu-flex and not Adobe Flex.

Comment: On your Flex file, add the option:

%option bison-locations

. And on your Bison file add:

%locations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the definition of `YYLTYPE` and `YYLTYPE_IS_DECLARED` into a header file that you `#include` in both your `.y` and `.l` files, and you need to `#include` the `.tab.h` file in your `.l` file AFTER the `#include` of the file that defines `YYLTYPE`.

The reason for the above is that bison DOES NOT export *your* definition of `YYLTYPE` from the top of your `.y` file, so if you want it somewhere else, you need to arrange that it be available.  Worse, the `.tab.h` file will always have the default `YYLTYPE` (guarded by `#ifndef YYLTYPE_IS_DECLARED`) so you need to ensure that your definition is seen before it.