# lex & yacc get current position

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lex, lexical-analysis

In lex & yacc there is a macro called YY_INPUT which can be redefined, for example in a such way

```
#define YY_INPUT(buf,result,maxlen) do { \
 const int n = gzread(gz_yyin, buf, maxlen); \                                                                              
 if (n < 0) { \
       int errNumber = 0; \
       reportError( gzerror(gz_yyin, &errNumber)); } \
     \
     result = n > 0 ? n : YY_NULL; \
  } while (0)
```

I have some grammar rule which called YYACCEPT macro.
If after YYACCEPT I called gztell (or ftell), then I got a wrong number, because parser already read some unnecessary data.

So how I can get current position if I have some rule which called YYACCEPT in it(one bad solution will be to read character by character)

(I have already done something like this:

```
#define YY_USER_ACTION do { \
        current_position += yyleng; \
} while (0)
```

but seems its not work
)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to keep track of the offset yourself. A simple but annoying solution is to put:

```
offset += yyleng;
```

in *every* flex action. Fortunately, you can do this implicitly by defining the `YY_USER_ACTION` macro, which is executed just before the token action.

That might still not be right for your grammar, because `bison` often reads one token ahead. So you'll also need to attach the value of `offset` to each lexical token, most conveniently using the location facility (`yylloc`).

**Edit: added more details on location tracking.**

*The following has not been tested. You should read the sections in both the `flex` and the `bison` manual about location tracking.*

The `yylloc` global variable and its default type are included in the generated bison code if you use the `--locations` command line option or the `%locations` directive, or if you simply refer to a location value in some rule, using the `@` syntax, which is analogous to the `$` syntax (that is, `@n` is the location value of the right-hand-side object whose semantic value is `$n`). Unfortunately, the default type for `yylloc` uses `int`s, which are not wide enough to hold a file offset, although you might not be planning on parsing files for which this matters. In any event, it's easy enough to change; you merely have to `#define` the `YYLTYPE` macro at the top of your `bison` file. The default `YYLTYPE` is:

```
typedef struct YYLTYPE
     {
       int first_line;
       int first_column;
       int last_line;
       int last_column;
     } YYLTYPE;
```

For a minimum modification, I'd suggest keeping the names unchanged; otherwise you'll also need to fix the `YYLLOC_DEFAULT` macro in your `bison` file. The default `YYLLOC_DEFAULT` ensures that non-terminals get a location value whose `first_line` and `first_column` members come from the first element in the non-terminal's RHS, and whose `last_line` and `last_column` members come from the last element. Since it is a macro, it will work with any assignable type for the various members, so it will be sufficient to change the `column` members to `long`, `size_t` or `offset_t`, as you feel appropriate:

```
#define YYLTYPE yyltype;
typedef struct yyltype {
  int first_line;
  offset_t first_column;
  int last_line;
  offset_t last_column;
} yyltype;
```

Then in your `flex` input, you could define the `YY_USER_ACTION` macro:

```
offset_t offset;
extern YYLTYPE yylloc;

#define YY_USER_ACTION         \
  offset += yyleng;            \
  yylloc.last_line = yylineno; \
  yylloc.last_column = offset;
```

With all that done and appropriate initialization, you should be able to use the appropriate `@n.last_column` in the `ACCEPT` rule to extract the offset of the end of the last token in the accepted input.

Comment: [rici](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) Could you please explain more detailed the last part of the answer(So you'll also need to attach the value of offset to each lexical token, using the location facility (yylloc), which you might already be using to keep track of line numbers).

Comment: For anyone who is struggling to get this to compile, I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10391395/2661880) helpful.