# How to Implement Jump instructions in lex and yacc

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I want to implement

```
             DJNZ R1,LABEL
```

That means Decrement R1 and Jump to LABEL if the result of decrementing is not zero.

I have lex file which generates a token DJNZ, REG and LABEL.

In the yacc file I have :

```
     Jump_instr: DJNZ REG ',' LABEL    {regmem[regIdx] = regmem[regIdx] -1;                                       
                                             if (regmem[regIdx] != 0)
                                              { goto label;}}
```

Iam not sure how to proceed. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

When your parser encounters a label, you need to add it to a hash table (commonly called a symbol table) with the corresponding instruction pointer. Since this appears to be an interpreter without an AST, your instruction pointer would be the index of the first character of the first instruction after the label (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25258536/31516) for one possible way to get a token's position). To "jump" to that label, you then look it up in the symbol table and restart the interpreter at that index. You won't be able to do this with C labels, because they must be known when you compile the interpreter.

Also, as it stands, your interpreter will only be able to jump backward. You can handle forward jumps by running two passes: the first to build the symbol table and a second to actually execute each instruction.

Comment: Yeah thank you. But Iam not sure how to add the instructions in the Hash table. Because LABEL could be another AST. also if DJNZ is ZERO, then it should continue with the next instructions. Can you suggest me some references so that I can go through for better understanding.