# How to resolve a yylloc undeclared error?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm new to flex and bison so bear with me. I'm trying to use yylloc in yyerror to print out where the error occurs along with the filename. I know that this requires me to redefine YYLTPYE to include a char* filename that I can use to keep track of the filename.  According to the Flex and Bison book I have, it recommends that I use the YY_USER_ACTION macro to initialize the YYLTYPE in the .l file, so I included the following in it,

```
#define YY_USER_ACTION yylloc.filename = filename; yylloc.hel = 0;  \
        yylloc.first_line = yylloc.last_line = yylineno;            \
        yylloc.first_column = yycolumn; yylloc.last_column = yycolumn+yyleng-1; \
        yycolumn += yyleng;
```

but when I try to compile the project, I get the error that yylloc is undeclared.

I've tried the solution offered by Chris Dodd in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386567/yylloc-undefined-in-this-scope), but it hasn't helped me to resolve the issue. Any and all help in resolving this error is much apprecaited.

Here's the full code in .l:

```
%option noyywrap nodefault yylineno case-insensitive
%{
    #include "need.h"
    #include "numbers.tab.h"

    int yycolumn = 1;

    #define YY_USER_ACTION yylloc.filename = filename; yylloc.hel = 0;  \
        yylloc.first_line = yylloc.last_line = yylineno;            \
        yylloc.first_column = yycolumn; yylloc.last_column = yycolumn+yyleng-1; \
        yycolumn += yyleng;

%}

Integers    [-]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)
Float       [.][0-9]+
Exp         [eE][-]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)
Octal       [-]?(00|0[1-7][0-7]*)
Hexa        [-]?(0[xX][0-9A-F]+)
tomsNotNumbers [^ \t\n\v\f\r]+

%%

{Integers}{Float}?{Exp}?    {
                                printf("%s is a number.\n", yytext);
                                possibleNumbers++;  // increment by 1 as an input was given -M
                                actualNumbers++;    // increment by 1 as an input did match our pattern -M
                            }

{Octal} {
            printf("%s is a number.\n", yytext);
            possibleNumbers++;  // increment by 1 as an input was given -M
            actualNumbers++;    // increment by 1 as an input did match our pattern -M
        }

{Hexa}  {
            printf("%s is a number.\n", yytext);
            possibleNumbers++;  // increment by 1 as an input was given -M
            actualNumbers++;    // increment by 1 as an input did match our pattern -M
        }

{tomsNotNumbers}    {
                    printf("%s is not a number.\n", yytext);
                    yyerror(warning, "This isn't a number.");
                    possibleNumbers++;  // increment by 1 as an input was given -M
                    failedNumbers++;    // increment by 1 as the input has failed to match our patterns -M
                }

[\n]    /*Do nothing for newline*/

.   /*Do nothing for anything else*/

%%
```

.y is just empty for now, only has an include for need.h and one for .tab.h

The need.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

int possibleNumbers = 0;
int actualNumbers = 0;
int failedNumbers = 0;

typedef struct YYLTYPE
{
    int first_line;
    int first_column;
    int last_line;
    int last_column;
    char *filename; /* use to keep track of which file we're currently in */
    int hel;    /* no errors = 0, warning = 1, error = 2, fatal = 3 */
} YYLTYPE;

char *name; /*using for test purposes*/

# define YYLTYPE_IS_DECLARED 1

# define YYLLOC_DEFAULT(Current, Rhs, N)                                                    \
    do                                                                                      \
        if (N)                                                                              \
        {                                                                                   \
            (Current).first_line = YYRHSLOC (Rhs, 1).first_line;                            \
            (Current).first_column = YYRHSLOC (Rhs, 1).first_column;                        \
            (Current).last_line = YYRHSLOC (Rhs, N).last_line;                              \
            (Current).last_column = YYRHSLOC (Rhs, N).last_column;                          \
            (Current).filename = YYRHSLOC (Rhs, 1).filename;                                \
            (Current).hel   = YYRHSLOC (Rhs, 1).hel;                                        \
        }                                                                                   \
        else                                                                                \
        { /* empty RHS */                                                                   \
            (Current).first_line = (Current).last_line = YYRHSLOC (Rhs, 0).last_line;       \
            (Current).first_column = (Current).last_column = YYRHSLOC (Rhs, 0).last_column; \
            (Current).filename  = NULL;                                                     \
            (Current).hel = 0;                                                              \
        }                                                                                   \
    while (0)

typedef enum errorSeverity
{
    warning = 1, error, fatal
} errorLevel;

void yyerror(errorLevel errlvl, char *s, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, s);
    char *errLvls[3] = {"Warning", "Error", "Fatal"};  

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: , %n", name, errLvls[errlvl - 1], yylloc.first_line);
    vfprintf(stderr, s, ap);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("argv[0] = %s, argv[1] = %s.\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        if((yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        {
            perror(argv[1]);
            exit(1);
        }
        name = argv[1];
    } else
        name = "(stdin)";

    printf("Filename1: %s", name);
    yylex();
    printf("Filename2: %s", name);
    // print out the report. -M
    printf("Out of %d possible numbers, there were %d numbers, and %d not numbers.\n", possibleNumbers, actualNumbers, failedNumbers);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `yylloc` is normally defined in the bison-generated parser, not having a bison input file is going to be a bit of a nuisance.

Bison will define `yylloc` in the generated parser, and place a declaration in the generated header file, if:

1. You include the directive `%locations` in the bison prologue, or
2. You reference a location (`@n` for some `n`) in any bison action.

It is generally preferred to add the directive in case there is no explicit reference to a location in any rule.

As Chris Dodd says in the linked question, it is important to include the definition of `YYLTYPE` before `#include`ing the bison-generated header file. Alternatively, you could insert the definition of the structure, or an appropriate `#include`, directly in the bison prologue in a `%code requires` section. `%code requires` sections are copied to the generated header, so that will obviate the need to worry about the definition in the flex file.

---

By the way, I think you meant to use `YY_USER_INIT` to *initialize* `yylloc`. The expansion of `YY_USER_INIT` is executed only once, before the flex scanner's own initialization. The expansion of `YY_USER_ACTION` is executed before every scanner action (including empty actions), and is likely to be of use to update the `yylloc` structure with the current token.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was able to get resolve the error by adding %locations and placing defintion of YYLTYPE in a %code requires block in the .y file. It's now saying undefined reference to 'yylloc' several times and then hits a collect@: error: ld returned 1 exit status. Is this because my parser doesn't have anything in it yet, or did I miss something.

Comment: Did you link the bison-generated parser into the executable?

Comment: here's my makefile:
numbers: numbers.l numbers.y
 bison -d numbers.y
 flex numbers.l
 gcc lex.yy.c numbers.tab.h -lfl

Comment: @havikiv: `numbers.tab.c`. you never compile `.h` files.

Comment: I tried that earlier, but this gave me more errors, vs the 1 error, which seemed the better choice XD. by linking the .tab.c, I'm getting an error: incompatible type for argument 1 of yyerror yyerror (YY_("syntax error")); From reading further into the error list, it seems that my definition of yyerror isn't being called, but rather the default built in one, If i'm reading it right

Comment: @havikiv: There is no builtin definition of yyerror. But you have to define it with the prototype that the parser expects, since the parser will call it.

Comment: @havikiv: also, it is a *really bad idea* to put function and variable *definitions* in a header file. Header files should only include declarations; otherwise you won't be able to use them in multifile projects. That probably explains many of the errors you have. Put the definitions in a separate `.c` file.

Comment: by changing the name of my definiton of yyerror to myyyerror, the earlier error was resolved, and now i'm back at error ld returned 1 exit. I'm assuming that this wasn't right as I'm getting undefined reference to myyyerror in yylex, and yyparse

Comment: @havik: you must declare and define yyerror, because yyparse requires it. You could define it to just call your error function easily enough. I strongly recommend that you find some introduction to program organisation over separate files, since you bison/flex projects inevitably involve multiple files (and because itbis an important part of learning how to program in C). I found this, which might be helpful, but there are many others (and any good C textbook should explain it, too) https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/separate-compilation/

Comment: i did define yyerror in the need.h, and I did separate the declaration and definition into the respective need.h and need.c files (atleast when you reminded me of the importance of organization, I orginally didn't care as this is just a dummy program to get a hang of flex/bison), but I was still getting the undefined reference error. I was able to resolve it by putting the definition in my .y file and, I had to remove the enum I was passing in to it, don't know why it had a problem with that, guess I can't override it.

Comment: I am getting similar error in RHEL8.7 with bison 3.0.4 and flex 2.6.1. I have added %locations along with YYLTYPE defintion and
void <classname>::error(const location_type& loc, const std::string& errorMsg)
{
      }

#define yyerror(S) error(yylloc, S)